# How do I take a screenshot on the iPad?

Tags: ipad

How do I create an image, containing a copy of the current screen display, on the iPad?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108423/discussion-on-question-by-bobby-jack-how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-on-the-ipad).

Answer (score 7):

Press both the sleep/wake and the home button simultaneously, and release quickly. The screenshot will be taken (in any app) and saved as an image, available within the Photos app.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple Pencil is the fastest way to screen shot an iPad since the buttons may be hard to reach. This also plays well into the new markup tools so you can quickly transform / edit and then share out that screen shot.

- swipe your Apple Pencil or finger from the bottom-left-corner on your iPad screen to take a screenshot (bottom-right is used for Quick Notes)
- you can also [press the sleep/volume up buttons](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210781) - release them together to snap
- you can also use accessibility + assistive touch to take a screenshot

Some great markup tips are at iMore: https://www.imore.com/screenshot-ipad
Apple’s markup guide is also quite helpful once you have your screenshot: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206885

Answer (score -2):

Press both the home button and the power button at the same time. This will save the screenshot to Photos. You can then edit the screenshot as you would a normal photo. I've noticed the screenshot comes in handy whenever you want to copy a photo, but are blocked from downloading it. :)

Comment: Hi @ThePianoGirl, welcome to Ask Different. Please be sure to make answers that add value to the OP and the site. In this case your answer seems to be almost identical to the one that already exists. You can edit a community wiki to improve it when you get enough reputation on the site.