# How do I record the iPad screen with a Netflix video playback in progress?

Tags: ipad, screen-capture, streaming, netflix

I am looking for a way to video record my iPad's screen while a Netflix video playback is in progress.

Is it possible to do while using the Netflix iPadOS app? Or do I have to use Chrome browser?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I record the iPad screen with a Netflix video playback in progress?

This is generally not a possible thing to do.

Capturing contents of the device screen by taking a screenshot or video recording is restricted programmatically in the iOS/iPadOS subsystem to curb on abusing the system.

You can neither do it while using a streaming app which provides access to protected content, nor by using a Web browser.

Consider going through these links which should give you some idea:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319665/ios-11-prevent-screen-record-like-netflix
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1970/_index.html

Netflix app has been programmed (using the help of iOS/iPadOS subsystem APIs) to curtail users from taking screenshot or record screen to keep a tab on potential gaming of the system. A screenshot or video recording would simply produce a black screen to discourage users from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to turn on AssistiveTouch, on your iPad, from the  Accessibility screen under Settings.  Once this is turned on a small gray circle appears on all your iPad screens.  You can take a screenshot using AssistiveTouch.  Taping on the gray circle opens a pane with 6 options. Tap on Device and another 6 options appear. Tap on More and another 6 options appear. The option in the top right corner is to take a screenshot. Tap that button and a screenshot will be taken. None of the panes associated with AssistiveTouch will appear in the screenshot.

I just tested this and it works fine.  I started AssistiveTouch and then went to Netflix.  A small gray circle appeared on my screen. You can move it to wherever you want by just dragging it with your finger. Then I went thru the panes until I got to the screenshot icon and took my shot. it worked well.

This may sound like a cumbersome way of getting a screenshot but after going thru it once it becomes a breeze.

This is needed since [the fast way to screenshot Netflix is blocked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-on-the-ipad) perhaps to slow us down making still images of a movie that theoretically or actually is copyright protected or licensed.

Comment: I just tried this and still got a black screenshot. This is using iOS 13.3.1 on a 9.7 inch iPad Pro.

Comment: OP is asking about taking a video screenshot, which as I understand means recording the screen while playing back a video in the Netflix app. Number two, Netflix app has been programmed to curtail users from taking screenshot or record screen to keep a tab on potential gaming of the system. A screenshot or video recording would simply produce a black screen.